# Is Truncate and Drop better then just Drop for a large table in sybase

Tags: sql, database, sybase, database-administration

I am using Sybase database and have a huge table ~ 300G and want to just get rid of it.
Tried Dropping the table but the command ran for more than 16 hrs and had to kill it because of logs filling up
What is the best way to do this? Will truncating table before drop help ?

Comment: Is it part of a subscription?

Comment: what do you mean by subscription ?

Comment: Subscriptions are used when a table is part of a Replication system.  It can cause some normally unlogged transactions to be logged.

Answer (score 0):

'DROP TABLE' should NOT be creating logs. I would check to see if another connection is accessing the table, thereby preventing its deletion.

TRUNCATE is a very fast way (in comparison to DELETE) to delete large amounts of data, and I've used it in the enterprise setting for giant tables we no longer cared about. It is much faster than DELETE, as it does not log the deletions. However, just make sure you have the proper permissions. It often won't work in production environments due to permission restrictions.

Read more on DROP here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X58548.htm

Comment: Thanks Sandra, my understanding is that both Drop and truncate do minimal logging and hence better then delete. However i did not find any reason to believe that whatever dint work with Drop will work with Truncate as in both cases there is minimal logging

Comment: Correct. That's why I suggested that there might be another connection accessing the table. As I mention in the second paragraph, TRUNCATE is only faster that DELETE (not DROP). Apologies if it wasn't clear!